# Is the Lebanese town of Nabatieh related in any way to the ancient Nabatean Civilization?

Tags: middle-east, arabia

Was Nabatieh in South Lebanon founded by the Nabateans of North Arabia(ex: Petra). If anyone finds some information on it, could you also please share the source so I can learn more about my ancestral hometown.

Comment: French Wikipedia has a little bit on this - [Nabatieh](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabatieh) - but it unfortunately lacks sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nabateans had an empire from the 4th century BC. They were an Arab nomadic tribe that settled in what is now Jordan. They expanded Northward through Syria. According to the maps I looked at they never made it further north and east then Damascus. In CE 363 there was an earthquake that cut off the Nabatean capital's, Petra, water supply. By 4th century the Nabateans were in decline.

I could not find a direct link between Nabatieh and the Nabateans.

The name may very well come from a post kingdom Nabatean settlement. Place names are sometimes made to describe the cultural group that resides or at one time resides in a place. For instance Little China or Little Italy in San Fransisco.

map - http://archive.aramcoworld.com/issue/200704/popup.htm?img=images/new.pieces/ARM6-02-Nabataean_lg.jpg

History- http://www.kinghussein.gov.jo/his_nabateans.html

Comment: "they never made it further north and east then Damascus" Nabatieh (Coordinates: 33°21′50″N 35°29′15″E) actually is in the west of Damascus (Coordinates: 33°30′47″N 36°17′31″E) and approximately the same latitude northwards . Arabic Wikipedia says that there are some asumptions that the Beaufort castle was built at the end of the Roman or during the Bizantine era.